# Drupal 8.6 Commerce: in .install file without module_uninstall() remove tables from database. Why?

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-8

When uninstall module then why delete all table from database without `module_uninstall()` function in *.install* file.

Also, why create table without `module_install()` function
*.install* file code is only:

```
function commerce_quickpay_schema() {
    $schema['webc_crypto_meta'] = [
        'description' => 'Custom Cryptography Meta',
        'fields' => [...],
        'primary key' => ['wcm_id'],
    ];
    $schema['webc_crypto_payment'] = [
        'description' => 'Custom Cryptography Payment',
        'fields' => [...],
        'primary key' => ['wcp_id'],
    ];
    return $schema;
}
```

Also, please, CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS condition in *.install* file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it behaves, the tables defined in hook_schema will be created or removed from the database when the module is installed or uninstalled, the hook_install() or hook_uninstall() hooks should be used when you want to do something extra.

It is simply assumed that the database schema should be removed when a module is uninstalled and come back when installed, if you think about it, it makes perfect sense.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_schema/8.7.x

> "The tables declared by this hook will be automatically created when
>   the module is installed, and removed when the module is uninstalled.
>   This happens before hook_install() is invoked, and after
>   hook_uninstall() is invoked, respectively."